# Complicated template involving constexpr and more

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to get better at writing complicated templates.  I've picked a sample problem in which I replace std::setw, std::setfill, and std::hex with something a little different.  (Note: this question isn't about iomanip.  The iomanip stuff is just a sample problem.  My goal is to learn some of the nuances of templates.)

So my first goal was to create a 'FormattedNumber' class that wraps an integer, and also carries formatting directives along as template parameters:

```
template<class VALUE, bool HEX, int WIDTH, char FILL>
class FormattedNumber {
public:
    VALUE val_;
    FormattedNumber(VALUE v) : val_(v) {}
};

template<class VALUE, bool HEX, int WIDTH, char FILL>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &oss, FormattedNumber<VALUE, HEX, WIDTH, FILL> n) {
    if (HEX) oss << std::hex;
    oss << std::setfill(FILL) << std::setw(WIDTH) << n.val_;
    oss << std::dec << std::setfill(' ');
    return oss;
}
```

That works fine.  It lets me write code like this:

```
std::cout << FormattedNumber<int, false, 0, ' '>(123);  //  '123'
std::cout << FormattedNumber<int, true, 4, '0'>(123);   //  '007b'
std::cout << FormattedNumber<int, false, 5, 'x'>(123);  //  'xx123'
```

So that's a start.  Next, step 2 was to make it easier to use.  I wanted to let the user write something friendly, like "hex.width(10).fill('0').make(123)".  I partially accomplished this:

```
template<bool HEX, int WIDTH, char FILL>
class NumberFormat {
public:
    constexpr static auto hex = NumberFormat<true, WIDTH, FILL>();
    constexpr static auto dec = NumberFormat<false, WIDTH, FILL>();

    constexpr static auto width5 = NumberFormat<HEX, 5, FILL>();
    constexpr static auto width10 = NumberFormat<HEX, 10, FILL>();

    constexpr static auto zfill = NumberFormat<HEX, WIDTH, '0'>();
    constexpr static auto xfill = NumberFormat<HEX, WIDTH, 'x'>();

    template<class VALUE>
    static FormattedNumber<VALUE, HEX, WIDTH, FILL> make(VALUE v) {
        return FormattedNumber<VALUE, HEX, WIDTH, FILL>(v);
    }
};

constexpr auto hex = NumberFormat<true, 0, '0'>();
constexpr auto dec = NumberFormat<false, 0, '0'>();
```

That does work, and it lets me write code like this:

```
std::cout << dec.width5.zfill.make(123);   // '00123'
std::cout << dec.width10.xfill.make(123);  // 'xxxxxxx123'
std::cout << hex.width5.xfill.make(123);   // 'xxx7b'
```

That's another step in the right direction, but I'd like to be able to change that in two ways.  First, I'd like to be able to write 'width(10)' instead of 'width10'.
Unfortunately, I've tried putting this into class NumberFormat:

```
    constexpr static auto width(int n) {
        return NumberFormat<HEX, ????, FILL>();
    }
```

But I just can't figure out what to put where the question marks are.  I could certainly do this instead:

```
    template<int N>
    constexpr static auto width() {
        return NumberFormat<HEX, N, FILL>();
    }
```

But that requires the user to write "width<5>()", which is ugly as heck.  It seems like this should be possible, if the parameter to width is an integer literal.

So the second thing I'd like to change is I'd like to be able to write "hex(123)" instead of "hex.make(123)".  The word "make" seems unnecessary.  I've tried adding this to the class:

```
    template<class VALUE>
    constexpr static auto operator()(VALUE v) {
        return FormattedNumber<VALUE, HEX, WIDTH, FILL>(v);
    }
```

But it doesn't like that, apparently operator() needs to be non-static.  I can make it non-static, but if I do that, the linker complains like this:

```
   undefined reference to `NumberFormat<false, 10, (char)48>::zfill'
```

That's weird, that's supposed to be a static constexpr, ie, just a constant, so it shouldn't have any linkage.  I don't understand this.

Can any of you explain if there's a way to do the 'width' function, and can you explain why that linkage is causing a problem?  Is there a way to make my "template magic" work better?

Comment: By using the wrong tool for the job, it make the code complicated. I think it would make more sense if FormattedNumber was not a template...

Comment: I appreciate your effort in learning. But, just why?  There is no reason to write complex code. You want it readable and useable.

Comment: Could you tell me how are you using instances of class NumberFormat inside its' definiton? How does that compile?

Comment: Complexity is not a goal, just an inevitable side effect. Try to simplify things - via decide & conquer e.g. I like what u tryna do, but alas that's gonna be much more complicated than this.

Comment: For your first issue, I believe you're trying to do an impossible. Function/method parameters can never be constant expressions, so you cannot instantiate a class template using function parameter value. For your second issue I'm not sure, but I feel like we should know the structure of your code (which parts of code are stored in which header etc.) to be able to answer.

Comment: Domdrag: as this is just a toy problem I'm doing for learning purposes, my code only has one source file.  All the code is right here in the question.

Comment: @jyelon I don't know then, the code relevant for operator() compiled for me on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n8WsTe7oK). Though, I still don't know does your NumberFormat class compile.

Comment: @jyelon any updates on this? Could you provide me your code on godbolt maybe?

Comment: No updates, I gave up.  Here's my code on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/6vr6j8GxW  It doesn't compile on godbolt, but it compiles fine on my machine.  No idea what that's about.  Never used godbolt before.

Comment: @jyelon Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/h8aKMYTE5) solve your second issue? Maybe the issue was that your operator() wasn't defined as const since you were using it on a const variable hex?

Comment: @jyelon Also, I believe the reason why it wasn't compiling on godbolt was because you can't use auto declaration on incomplete types.